# Camel bindy separator configurable through properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, apache-camel, bindy

I use Apache Camel in a Spring Boot Java project. I have to parse a csv and split the lines with a separator. I use [camel bindy](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/dataformats/bindy-dataformat.html) to parse the csv and read it as a pojo bean class.

Here is how I configure the camel bindy

```
@CsvRecord( separator = "," )
public Class MyClass {
}
```

Here is my question: how can I change the separator value dynamically, reading it from a property? I've tried `@CsvRecord( separator = "${my-prop.separator}" )` but it did not work.

Comment: It doesn't look like Bindy supports runtime configuration of separator.

Comment: it is what I supposed, can I do something with spring and dependency injection?

Comment: Not that I know of. If you have a known set of delimiters, you could have a separate DTO class (w/ @CsvRecord annotation) for each one, i.e. MyClassComma, MyClassSemicolon, etc. Then at runtime choose the correct DTO class based on a spring property that specifies the delimiter.

Comment: Thanks, if you answer I'll accept it and close the post

Comment: ok added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of. If you have a known set of delimiters, you could have a separate DTO class (w/ @CsvRecord annotation) for each one, i.e. MyClassComma, MyClassSemicolon, etc. Then at runtime choose the correct DTO class based on a spring property that specifies the delimiter.